# JS: Use array destructuring (eslintprefer-destructuring)

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructuring

I am getting the ESLint error (**Use array destructuring. eslint(prefer-destructuring)**) when I do:

```
let foo = 1;
foo = obj.data[i][1]; //ESLint error on this line
```

Can anyone please help to fix this?

Comment: Turn off that eslint rule, this warning is daft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESlint wants you to write

```
let foo = 1;
[, foo] = obj.data[i];
```

Whether that's actually better if up to you to decide. If you don't like it, turn off that rule instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this rule by placing `/* eslint-disable prefer-destructuring */` at the beginning of the file or try to destructure it:

```
let foo = 1;
[, foo] = obj.data[i];
```